# Correctly check if user is logged in. Android

Tags: java, android

I have my login setup like this, I use retrofit to authenticate from the server and I'm using a token api authentication:

In the MainActivity.java method onCreate

```
apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

User user = SharedPreferencesHelper.getUser(MainActivity.this);

if (user.getToken() == null) {
    Intent login = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(login);
} else {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    buildMain();
}
```

In the LoginActivity.java method on create (I'll summarize, the code is quite long)

```
loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //get login ingo

        Login login = new Login(scardI, passwordI, device_name);

        Call<User> call = apiInterface.LoginUser(login);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    User user = response.body();
                    //save user info into SharedPreferences
                    SharedPreferencesHelper.setUser(LoginActivity.this, user);

                    //check if user saved correctly by getting the user token
                    if (SharedPreferencesHelper.getUserToken(LoginActivity.this) != null) {
                        finish();
                    }
                } else {
                    //show error message
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                //show error message
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I'm having an issue, after the user logs in a blank page is displayed instead of the `activity_main.xml` however when I close the app and reopen it it takes me straight to the `activity_main.xml` as expected. Is there a reason that after the login it doesn't take me to the activity_main like expected.

Comment: Your method is in onCreate. After finish() it doesn't work.  Put your method in onResume()

Answer (score 1):

An intent to MainActivity.java is missing on success. A blank screen is displayed because finish() is called.

```java
 if (response.isSuccessful()) {
     User user = response.body();
     SharedPreferencesHelper.setUser(LoginActivity.this, user);
      if (SharedPreferencesHelper.getUserToken(LoginActivity.this) != null){
       Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
       i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
       startActivity(i);
}

}
```

Comment: I had been told not to do that for performance reasons, and was suggested to use finish instead does it matter that much?

Comment: The only reason you might have been asked to call finish would be to clear LoginActivity from the back stack. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: would a parent activity be relevant in this case?

Comment: What the above code does is. It takes you to MainActivity and removes LoginActivity from stack. Same as calling finish() on LoginActivity. So when you press back you wont be taken back to LoginActivity